# Without creating GCP VM instance, how to create firewall rules to allow traffic from one VPC network to another VPC network using IP ranges

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall, google-vpc

Am having 2 VPC networks. 1 VPC is related to webserver which will allow traffic from internet. This webserver network having 2 subnets with various IP ranges. Another VPC is related to mySQL database. This is having 1 subnet. For database server I need to allow traffic only from webserver network subnets. For that i need to create one firewall rule by applying IP ranges of webserver network. How can we implement this?

Note: we don't have access to create and assign tags from VM instances for this project.

Tried to create VM instances and network tags. But there is no access to create them. Also provided IP ranges of 2 subsets from webserver and allowed all on protocol and ports.

Comment: Did you activate the APIs?